# Does the MB chipset have to support 802.11ac?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

So I have an older Acer laptop (model 5750-6664), and I am going to upgrade my Wifi network to AC, and my laptop is only N. i was thinking about upgrading my WLAN card but I dont know if the CPU or chipset has to support AC or is all on the WLAN card? or are AC cards and N card keyed differently?

(I know i can connect an N device to an AC router)

thank you

Comment: Just upgrade the WiFi module that supports 802.11ac

Answer (score 1):

A regular WiFi card is entirely self-contained (except for the antenna). It interfaces with the PC using the PCIe bus and as such requires no explicit hardware support.

Most notebook WiFi cards also have Bluetooth built-in. This part of the card is usually connected to the host via USB, which is also available on the Mini PCIe connector.

As such, you can swap cards as you like, as long as both card have the same host connector – usually Mini PCIe, though it may be M.2 in the future.

A word of warning, though: Many notebook makers implement a whitelist of allowed WiFi cards in their notebooks. They assert this is necessary to comply with FCC rules. That’s FUD, of course. Still, you can’t do anything about it.

Comment: It's not entirely fud, only partially fud, the other half is just lazy.  Similar to the router OEMs blacklisting custom firmware to comply with a new FCC ruling with regards to router frequency